# VueJS Axios API, trying to get only 1 result, not many

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, v-for

I'm trying to get only 1 response from the Nasa images API using VueJS and Axios. I've followed the tutorial here(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiIQce7Rx4Y&t=939s) and the app is working just like shown. But this tutorial shows how to get the complete list of images available through this API, I only want the first image but can't figure out how.

Here's the code for the api component:

```
<template>
 <div class="search">
  <section id="sectionB">
   <h2>Type in your search term</h2>
   <form v-on:submit.prevent="getResult(query)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type in your search" v-model="query" />
   </form>
   <br/>
   <div v-if="results">
    <div v-for="result in results" v-bind:key="result">
     <img v-bind:src="result.links[0].href" class="imgContainer" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import axios from "axios";
 export default {
  name: "search",
  data() {
   return {
    msg: "Search",
    query: "",
    results: "",
     };
   },
  methods: {
   getResult(query) {
    axios.get(
      "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=" + query + "&media_type=image"
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.collection.items);
      this.results = response.data.collection.items;
    });
   },
  },
 };
</script>
```

I tried removing f-for to stop the loop but that removed all images, not just everyone after the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the documentation of the API on the website of Nasa: https://images.nasa.gov/docs/images.nasa.gov_api_docs.pdf. The only endpoint they have that returns images is the `search` endpoint that you are using.

However, reading your question again.. You can just show the first of the list (array) of results: `results[0]`, like below:

```
   <div v-if="results">
     <img v-bind:src="results[0].links[0].href" class="imgContainer" />
   </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help and welcome to stackoverflow.